# Why don't I see my applications in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I am running Mac OS 11.2.3. When I go into Terminal and type

`cd ~/Applications`

Followed by

`ls`

Nothing is listed there. My applications are under the hard drive. How do I access them from Terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applications that come with macOS are found in `/System/Applications`. User-installed applications are usually found in `/Applications`. `~/Applications` is usually only used if you have a non-administrator account.

Comment: Note that `~/Applications` usually doesn't even exist. It generally only gets created when it's needed to hold a per-user-installed app. Since there aren't any there in this case, it's a bit of a mystery why it's there at all. Maybe something got installed & then removed, or maybe an installer got confused and created it unnecessarily, or... who knows. Anyway, it's not a problem or anything, just a bit unusual.